# Kohana Hierarchical Routes with Subpages

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, kohana

I'd like to set up some kind of hierarchical routing in Kohana 3.0.9. The routing should support pages and sub-pages, which could look something like this:

URL called: `http://example.com/company/contact/`

Possible Route: `<page>(/<subpage>(/<action>))`

The problem with above mentioned route is that it only supports a hierarchy with two levels. If the site needed to be able to handle "sub-sub-pages" like `http://example.com/company/contact/sub`, I would have to change the route.

Also, I'd like one single page controller to handle the request. It could, for example, accept `company/contact/sub` as a string parameter. I'm aware of the `<directory>` key and I'm not planning to use it.

Is there any way to make the route "compatible" with unlimited nested pages?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the ROUTING section, you can create custom REGEX patterns.
(read here)  http://kohanaframework.org/guide/kohana/routing

By default, routing "parameters" removes punctuation.

You can setup a regex to accept "/".

Then you can grab the last parameter and explode it with
$pieces = explode("/", $pizza);

Example:
http://example.com/company/contact/subpage/subsubpage/action

```
Route::set('multilevel', '(<controller>(/<page_levels>/<action>))'
, array('page_levels' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'page_controller',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Doublecheck the REGEX, but basically it grabs all "/" except the very last one (which should be your ACTION parameter separator.

In your **ACTION_[action]** function (in **Controller_Contact** for this example),
you would then call

```
$page_levels = Request::instance()->param('page_levels');
$page_array  = explode("/",$page_levels);
```

This should get you

```
 $page_array = array ( [1] => 'contact',
                       [2] => 'subpage',
                       [3] => 'subsubpage')
```

Comment: Looks good, however the Regex didn't work. I changed it to `(.*)`, but unfortunately the action gets cut off. `page_levels` would contain `bonjour/sub/doublesub/index` for http://localhost/kohana/page/bonjour/sub/doublesub/index.

Comment: @daniel, you could either try (.*)/  OR hardcode ACTION into you route to (<controller>(/<page_levels>/my_action))  and then set 'action' => 'my_action'  to hardcode in the action parameter.  I am not sure how many different actions you have.

Comment: @daniel change your ROUTE to following.
Route::set('multilevel', '(<controller>(/<page_levels>/<action>))'
, array('page_levels' => '.*'))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunately. I'll try to exclude the action through the regex – might use something like `(.*)/(index|edit)?`.

Comment: Important: We both forgot that the regular expression is only for checking whether it matches the url string – it will never modify or cut off parts of the url. I guess I'll have to hack the Kohana source then.